# Debugging "Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

I received this error in response to a SQL query:

```
SQL Error: column "source.has_sent_a_message" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The column "source.has_sent_a_message" appears in both SELECT and FROM, as well as the GROUP BY and ORDER BY; what should I try next to debug?

UPDATE: I've been asked to add the full query, which is as follows:

```
SELECT "source"."has_sent_a_message" AS "has_sent_a_message", "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message" AS "has_received_a_response_to_first_message", "source"."Difference Between 1x0 and 1x1" AS "Difference Between 1x0 and 1x1"
FROM (SELECT "source"."has_sent_a_message" AS "has_sent_a_message", "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message" AS "has_received_a_response_to_first_message", (sum(CASE WHEN "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message" = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0.0 END) - sum(CASE WHEN "source"."has_sent_a_message" = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0.0 END)) AS "Difference Between 1x0 and 1x1" FROM (SELECT "source"."has_sent_a_message" AS "has_sent_a_message", "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message" AS "has_received_a_response_to_first_message" FROM (with users_having_connected as (
    select u.id as user_id,
           (a.connected_at is not null) has_connected
    from core_user u
    join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
    join core_conversation c on (c.profile1_id = p.id or c.profile2_id = p.id)
    join analytics_connection a on c.id = a.conversation_id
    group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)
)
select u.id as user_id,
       date_trunc('month', u.created at time zone 'UTC')::date as month,
       p.community_id,
       p.organization_id,
       p.profile_type_intention,
       (p.basic_account_completed and (p.is_mentor or p.is_entrepreneur)) as profile_is_completed,
       exists(select 1 from core_message where core_message.sender_id = p.id) as has_sent_a_message,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM core_admin_conversation_w_resp
WHERE core_admin_conversation_w_resp.initiator_id = p.id)) AS has_received_a_response_to_first_message,
       exists(select 1 from users_having_connected where user_id = u.id) as has_connected
from core_user as u
join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
where
p.profile_type_intention is not null) "source"
LEFT JOIN "public"."core_profile" "Core Profile" ON "source"."user_id" = "Core Profile"."user_id" LEFT JOIN "public"."core_user" "Core User" ON "source"."user_id" = "Core User"."id" WHERE ("Core Profile"."community_id" = 130
    OR "Core Profile"."community_id" = 131)
GROUP BY "source"."has_sent_a_message", "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message"
ORDER BY "source"."has_sent_a_message" ASC, "source"."has_received_a_response_to_first_message" ASC) "source") "source"
LIMIT 1048575
```

Comment: Without the original query there is really no way to answer this. Add the query as update to your question.

Comment: I'm going to say it is coming from your first sub-select: `SELECT "source"."has_sent_a_message" AS "has_sent_a_message" ... group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)`.

Comment: You should start by formatting the query in a sensible way, and not re-using the same alias over and over.